# Form I-944 or I-864 for a Derivative Applicant of a employment based Principal Applicant

Tags: immigration, greencard

I have approved I-140 and am planning to file I-485 for me and my wife. I know that I have to file I-944 as I am an Employment-Based Alien Worker.

Could you please tell me whether I have to file I-944 or I-864 for my wife?

Answer (score 2):

I-864 is not needed for either of you because you are immigrating in an employment-based category (derivative beneficiaries have the same category as the principal beneficiary), as long as the petitioning company is not 5% or more owned by your relative. <s>Both of you would need to file I-944, the public charge questionnaire. Employment-based immigrants are not exempt from the public charge ground of inadmissibility.</s>

**Update:** As of March 9, 2021, the public charge rule has been vacated. Neither of you should file I-944 with your I-485. See the alert at the top of the [I-485 page](https://www.uscis.gov/i-485).

In [I-485 instructions](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/i-485instr-pc.pdf), the section "Public Charge:  Declaration of Self-Sufficiency (Form I-944) and Affidavit of Support Under Section 213A of the INA (Form I-864)" (on page 12-15) lists which categories need to file I-864 <s>or I-944 or both</s> or neither:

> Who Must Submit Form I-944 (and not Form I-864)
>
> If you are a principal or derivative applicant, you must submit Form
> I-944 with your Form I-485 if you are applying under one of the
> following immigrant categories:
>
> [...]
>
> B. Alien worker under the employment-based preference categories
> (Exception:  You may also need to file Form I-864 if a relative filed
> Form I-140 for you or has five percent or more ownership interest in
> the business that filed Form I-140 for you.  See the list above for
> more details.);

On both of your I-485 forms you would check "No" in I-485, Part 8, item 61, "Are you exempt from the public charge ground of inadmissibility?". And then both of you would check the box in Part 8, item 62d,

> I am EXEMPT from filing Form I-864 because:
>
> 62.d. I am applying under an alien worker (Form I-140) employment-based preference immigrant category and both of the
> following apply:
>
> (1) I am not a relative of the Form I-140 petitioner; and
>
> (2) I do not have a relative with a significant ownership interest (at
> least five percent) in the business that filed Form I-140.